# Passing data back to form on invalid submission

Tags: routes, controller, validation

I currently have a form that is being displayed to the user via a custom route.

The form submits to a controller. The first thing the controller does is populate a custom model and validates it.

If the model fails validation, I want to skip the rest of the controller and pass the model back to the form. What is the best way to do this? I tried using `craft()->urlManager->setRouteVariables` and a `$this->redirect`, but the route variable didn't seem to come through, which I imagine is because `setRouteVariables` isn't supposed to be used like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `setRouteVariables` and not return anything from your controller so the request continues as normal.  Craft does this all the time with it's own controllers.  See [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/12033/57) for the general controller workflow.

Comment: This is definitely the better way to handle it. I saw how Craft was doing it, but I didn't understand that returning nothing without redirecting would reload the original page. Thank you for this information!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I realized even though the template is being called via route, it's still a template, duh. So I can use `$this->renderTemplate` in the controller and specify the data there. Is there a more elegant way than this though?